# Set user control properties dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I am currently developing a custom role/permission system...

I have a user control with all my permissions already and i want to re-use it for my custom role editor.

So right now I have a dropdownlist of the custom roles and a textbox to edit the name. What I want to do is...everytime a new value is selected in the dropdownlist the page to refresh and re-load my permission control with the RoleID and RoleName properties to be set to the DDL.SelectedValue and the textbox.Text like so...

```
<RSIPD:Permissions ID="Permissions" RoleID="[lstBaseRoles.SelectedValue]" RoleName="[txtCustomRoleName.Text]" runat="server" />
```

I know I am probably going about this the wrong way as I am more familiar with MVC3 than traditional ASP.NET Webform and am still learning.

Comment: I already know the above syntax is not valid it's just a way to show what values I want and where for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in the code behind:

```
Permissions.RoleID = lstBaseRoles.SelectedValue
Permissions.RoleName = txtCustomRoleName.Text
```

This code would need to be called in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your DropDownList, and the `TextChanged` event of your TextBox.

Comment: Thanks Curt. Of course it would be that simple and I was completely over-thinking it :P